# Any function similar to Notify() (this method is used in java thread) in vb.net

Tags: java, vb.net

Is there any method similar to Notify() in vb.net, or how to implement the similar functionality in vb.net

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NotifyIcon tool in vb.net....NotifyIcon tool displays an icon in the notification area, on the right side of the windows taskbar during runtime.

Steps to add NotifyIcon tool to our application.

Step 1: Add a NotifyIcon to the form (or application) from the toolbox

Step 2: Take properties of notifyIcon and change the text property with name of your project

Step 3: Select icon for the NotifyIcon

Step 4: Select BalloonTipIcon for showing tips that you give, tips can be given in BalloonTipText

Step 5: Now run the program you can see icon in taskbar

Answer (score 0):

Use [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) class methods.